# Flutter Memory Leak

Tags: android, flutter

why am I getting memory leak error when I am not initializing anything in `initstate`
I am new to flutter so I do not know much about memory leak but I have read that app is blocked if there is a memory leak. the App is running fine but this error occurs
The error is:-

```
E/flutter (18881): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _MovieGalleryState#74812(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
E/flutter (18881): This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
E/flutter (18881): The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
E/flutter (18881): This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
E/flutter (18881): #0      State.setState.<anonymous closure>
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1233
E/flutter (18881): #1      State.setState
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:1268
E/flutter (18881): #2      _MovieGalleryState._searchQuery
package:ottapp/screens/moviegallery.dart:134
E/flutter (18881): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (18881): #3      _MovieGalleryState.initState
```

This is the code

```
class _SearchPageState extends State<SearchPage> {

  List<Movie> searchResult = [];
  bool isLoading = false;

  _searchQuery(String query) async {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
    setState(() {
      isLoading = true;
    });
    QuerySnapshot snapshot = await movieRef.where('title',isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: query).get();
    searchResult = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => Movie.fromdocument(doc)).toList();
    setState(() {
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TextField(
                onSubmitted: (query){
                  _searchQuery(query);
                },
              ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: GridView.count(
                crossAxisCount:3,
                children: searchResult,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
  }
  @override
  void dispose() { 
    
    super.dispose();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is that there is not enough space to implement the array

Error in arranging the widget: you should follow the next method:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SingleChildScrollView( //Edit her 
      child: Column(
        children: [
          TextField(
            onSubmitted: (query){
              _searchQuery(query);
            },
          ),
          Expanded( // Edit her
            child: GridView.count(
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              crossAxisCount:3,
              shrinkWrap: true,
              
              children: searchResult,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```